# Могу ли я задать для всех тегов <p> моего HTML один стиль в CSS?

Tags: html, css

Я не знаю насколько это разумно, но наш преподаватель говорит, что мы не можем напрямую из CSS обращаться к тегам HTML, это плохая практика.

То есть вот такой html: `<p>blablabla</p>` и стили `p {color:green;}` - это неправильно.

А правильно на каждый абзац писать `<p class='green'>blablabla</p>`, а потом в CSS файле `.green {color:green;}`.

Всё то же самое про ссылки, списки и тд.

Мне это кажется немного нелогичным. Как же правильно?

Comment: Если у вас весь текст одним цветом, вполне нормальный способ p{color: value;}

Comment: @soledar10 Я также и сказал, на что получил ответ: "А вдруг ты этот же CSS файл подключишь к другому HTML документу?"

Comment: Ну правильно было сказано про "а вдруг". Но если есть железобетонная уверенность, что стили будут работать только на текущей странице (и на других, где всё равно нужен тот же стиль) - спокойно можно писать p {color...}.

Comment: Странный препод... А что, если названия стилей будут пересекаться? Все зависит от задач. Посмотрите как устроен bootstrap.

Comment: Ну «а вдруг» завтра приспичит переделать `<p>` в `<div>`? Придётся все стили переписывать :)

Answer (score 1):

**Совет:** слушайте вашего преподавателя внимательно и внимайте!!!

Я уверена, что преподаватель свои утверждения обосновал,  возможно Вы что-то упустили.

Все зависти от задачи.

**Вариант 1. Нужно задать всем параграфам одинаковые стили, зеленый цвет текста:**

```css
p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates nulla eos molestiae aspernatur quas dolor, eum officiis culpa cupiditate ab.
  </p>
</main>

<footer>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, est.
  </p>
</footer>
```

**Вариант 2. Нужно задать зеленый цвет текста только параграфу внутри второй секции основного контента в третьем `div` .... (для случая со сложной разметкой).**

Сможете ли Вы задать стили только через один лишь тег?! Возможно, и сможете, но это будет выглядеть примерно так: `main>div+div>p { color: green; }`.

Не очень приятная запись. А теперь представьте, что со временем в разметку вносятся изменения и ваш параграф смещается или переносится в другой блок, но он все так же должен быть зеленого цвета!

Вот именно из-за возможных изменений и манипуляций с разметкой (html) лучше задавать блокам классы.

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates nulla eos molestiae aspernatur quas dolor, eum officiis culpa cupiditate ab.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero, fuga.
  </p>


  <section>
    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="green">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>

<footer>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, est.
  </p>
</footer>
```

---

[**Подробнее о приоритетах.**](https://webref.ru/course/css-basics/priority)

[**Статья о верстке с помощью БЭМ.**](https://habr.com/ru/post/203440/)

**P.S:** Параграф `p` приводится исключительно в качестве примера. Все это касается любого другого `html` элемента и задание для него стилей.

**Если проще:**

- Используем для всех элементов на странице одни и те же стили везде и всегда - можно задавать стили через тег!

  Пример:

  ```
    p {
        margin: 0 0 1rem;
      }

    ul {
        padding: 0;
      }

    ul>li {
      color: #333;
    }
  ```
- Элемент имеет свои собственные стили (не все параграфы,а только определенные), элемент может использоваться в любом месте разметки (не теряя стили), к элементу должен быть доступ для других разработчиков - используем `class` или `id`.

  Пример:

```css
.green {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates nulla eos molestiae aspernatur quas dolor, eum officiis culpa cupiditate ab.
  </p>

  <section>
    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <article>
        <p class="green">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Писать стиль для тэга плохая практика потому что ты никогда не знаешь что потом может быть с твоей версткой, после тебя придет другой верстальщик добавить там кнопочки или что-то нибудь и столкнется с тем что ты тэгам определил стили а не классам, и он матерясь будет переписывать весь css, это кстати одна из причин почему придумали классы и почему придумали фреймворки по типу Bootstrap, Polymer и тд. потому что нужно что бы другой разработчик сходу понимал что у тебя написано и не тратил время на понимание всей твоей верстки.

Comment: На весь ответ всего две точки — да вы издеваетесь, это ж тяжело читать